# Google Chrome sandbox

Tags: html, webforms, google-chrome

Em algumas páginas de um sistema no qual eu trabalho (não sou o único desenvolvedor) aparece uma mensagem no Google Chrome como a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso só acontece no Google Chrome, no Firefox funciona normalmente.

No servidor de testes também funciona, inclusive no Google Chrome.

Nos servidores de produção (são 3 com balanceamento de carga via DNS se não me engano) ocorre o descrito acima.

Não sei como fazer para resolver este problema, que como disse anteriormente, acontece apenas em algumas páginas.

Já pesquisei e não encontrei nada que pudesse me dar uma luz sobre como funciona essa ideia de sandbox no Chrome.

As páginas não possuem nenhum `<iframe>`.

Se alguém possuir algum material que me ajude a entender o motivo disso estar ocorrendo, eu agradeço.

Se alguém souber como resolver será de grande ajuda, porém peço que me mostre como identificar o motivo desse comportamento e não só a solução.

Comment: Pelo que vi, você que coloca que quer o seu iframe como sandbox.

Comment: Da uma olhadinha nessa questão: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531061/blocked-script-execution-in-because-the-documents-frame-is-sandboxed-angular

Comment: estranho o erro sem envolver iframes, pode desabilitar suas extensões no chrome e testar novamente?

Comment: Faça o seguinte também: inicie o chrome com esses argumentos: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --allow-scripts

Answer (score -1):

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662

*Unsandboxed plugin access*

Não ví isso ocorrer ams por acontecer pra um usuário e pra outro não, resta configuração particular do browser.
Outra opção é que cocê pode estar em uma área com um certificado inválido e sua configuração está bloqueando o script devido o conflito do certificado.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência. As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada